# UIWebView control when navigating within page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am currently doing all my logic under `webViewDidFinishLoad` and I realize that when just jumping to another section (go to `#section` of the page), it doesn't reload the page therefore it doesn't call the `webViewDidFinishLoad` method. I was wondering if there's another method that gets called when I'm just jumping around the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: should be call, if not, you may try to jumping to another section from javascript and call objc method

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215

Comment: `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` does get called. Thanks!